# Resetting iPhone to factory settings programmatically

Tags: ios

Is there a way where we can programmatically reset the iPhone settings to factory default settings? We have a Reset Option in General section of the Settings application. Can we access that programmatically?

Thanks
Sudheer

Answer (score 4):

This isn't supported by the SDK. There might be something you can do with jailbroken phones (which would obviously limit distribution), but through the official SDK, there isn't any way.